# How can I compress an object in Unity?

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, compression

I am an Android programmer, and I need to compress object's size like how WinRAR works for decreasing the size of folders and many file formats.

Please suggest software for decreasing the size of objects by compressing or decreasing polygons without changing quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few ways to do this. Assuming your objects are in .FBX format or .3DS or similar, Blender is a handy tool for any form of object changes, including reducing polygon count.  Check out the tutorial below on how to do so via blender:

http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/decimate.html

Once reduced, save and reimport/replace existing object back into the game. You can see the reduction in real time so you can find that sweet spot for when you feel the object is reduced too much.

If you want something within Unity, cruncher or simplygon are available in the asset store which is targetted to reduce polygon counts.

Simplygon

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10144

Cruncher

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/4294

Hope this helps.